# error al llamar un formulario nuevamente en visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

tengo un formulario donde ingreso un codigo y al dar click en el boton de imprimir me abre un nuevo formulario donde se visualiza el reporte pero cuando cierro esa ventana del reporte ingreso un nuevo codigo y le doy a imprimir me sale el error de que "no se puede tener acceso al objeto eliminado" al hacer un debugeo me muestra el error en la linea donde estoy llamando a mi formulario que contiene el reporte , en el enlace muestro imagen del error

este es el formulario principal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace liquidaciones
{
    public partial class Form2 : DevComponents.DotNetBar.Office2007Form
    {
        public DataTable dt;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("muni");
            dt.Columns.Add("f_zn");
            dt.Columns.Add("f_ag");
            dt.Columns.Add("total_tms");
            dt.Columns.Add("tms_lote");
            dt.Columns.Add("tms_lot_ant");
            dt.Columns.Add("tms_sig_lote");
            dt.Columns.Add("lote");

            dgv_senarecom.DataSource = dt;

        }

        private static Form2 m_FormDefInstance;
        public static Form2 DefInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_FormDefInstance == null || m_FormDefInstance.IsDisposed)
                    m_FormDefInstance = new Form2();
                return m_FormDefInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                m_FormDefInstance = value;
            }
        }

        private void Buscar_ids_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;


            string query = "select cast(count(*) as int) as cant from liquidacion_id_senarecom where id = '" + IDS_.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(query, session.miConexion);
            session.miConexion.Open();
            //SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
            //DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            //data.Fill(tabla);

            SqlDataReader registro = comd.ExecuteReader();

            if (registro.Read())
            {

                //valor = Convert.ToInt32(tabla);
                TOTAL_IDS.Text = registro["cant"].ToString();
                x = Convert.ToInt32(USADOS.Text = registro["cant"].ToString());
            }
            session.miConexion.Close();

            string query2 = "select cast (count (*) as int) as used from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo where lid.id = '" + IDS_.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand comd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, session.miConexion);
            session.miConexion.Open();
            SqlDataReader usados = comd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (usados.Read())
            {
                USADOS.Text = usados["used"].ToString();
                y = Convert.ToInt32(USADOS.Text = usados["used"].ToString());
            }

            session.miConexion.Close();

            LIBRES.Text = Convert.ToString(x - y);


            if (IDS_.Text != "" && LOTE_.Text != "")
            {
                float tms = 0;
                string total_tms = "select sum(TMS) as tms from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion where lid.id = '" + IDS_.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand t_tms = new SqlCommand(total_tms, session.miConexion);
                session.miConexion.Open();
                SqlDataReader tms_total = t_tms.ExecuteReader();
                if (tms_total.Read())
                {
                    T_TMS.Text = tms_total["tms"].ToString();
                    tms = Convert.ToSingle(T_TMS.Text = tms_total["tms"].ToString());
                    //tms = decimal.ToInt32(T_TMS.Text = tms_total["tms"].ToString());
                }
                session.miConexion.Close();




                float tms_lo = 0;
                float tms_peso = 0;
                string sql1 = "select sum(TMS) as tms_li  from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo where lid.id = '" + IDS_.Text + "'and clt.lote= '" + LOTE_.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand com_tms = new SqlCommand(sql1, session.miConexion);
                session.miConexion.Open();
                SqlDataReader tms_lote = com_tms.ExecuteReader();
                if (tms_lote.Read())
                {
                    TMSLOTE.Text = tms_lote["tms_li"].ToString();
                    tms_lo = Convert.ToSingle(TMSLOTE.Text = tms_lote["tms_li"].ToString());
                    //tms = decimal.ToInt32(T_TMS.Text = tms_total["tms"].ToString());

                }
                session.miConexion.Close();

                //////////////////////////////////////


                string where = "";
                float sum = 0;
                string con_sum;
                String c;
                float tms2 = 0;
                string peso;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_listlote.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
                    {
                        c = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        where = "select sum(TMS) as tms_li from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo where lid.id = '" + txt_listlote.Text + "' and clt.lote = '" + c + "'";
                        SqlCommand s_tms = new SqlCommand(where, session.miConexion);
                        session.miConexion.Open();
                        SqlDataReader sum_total = s_tms.ExecuteReader();
                        if (sum_total.Read())
                        {
                            peso = sum_total["tms_li"].ToString();
                            tms2 = Convert.ToSingle(peso = sum_total["tms_li"].ToString());
                            sum = tms2 + sum;
                            suma_lotes_a.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
                        }
                        session.miConexion.Close();

                        TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - sum);
                        //TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - Convert.ToSingle(suma_lotes_a.Text));
                        /*if (Convert.ToInt32(LIBRES.Text) != 0)
                        {
                            //TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - tms_lo);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            T_TMS.Text = Convert.ToString(TMS_ID.Text);
                            TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(0);

                        }*/

                    }
                }








                /*TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - tms_lo);
                //TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - Convert.ToSingle(suma_lotes_a.Text));
                if (Convert.ToInt32(LIBRES.Text) != 0)
                {
                    //TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - tms_lo);
                }
                else
                {
                    T_TMS.Text = Convert.ToString(TMS_ID.Text);
                    TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
                    
                }*/




                float tmh_lo = 0;
                //float tmh_peso = 0;
                string sql2 = "select sum(TMH) as tmh_l  from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo where lid.id = '" + IDS_.Text + "'and clt.lote= '" + LOTE_.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand com_tmh = new SqlCommand(sql2, session.miConexion);
                session.miConexion.Open();
                SqlDataReader tmh_lote = com_tmh.ExecuteReader();
                if (tmh_lote.Read())
                {
                    TMN_L.Text = tmh_lote["tmh_l"].ToString();
                    tmh_lo = Convert.ToSingle(TMN_L.Text = tmh_lote["tmh_l"].ToString());
                    //tms = decimal.ToInt32(T_TMS.Text = tms_total["tms"].ToString());

                }
                session.miConexion.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Mensaje.Mostrar("Llene todos los campos.", MensajeIcono.Alert);
            }

        }

        private void list_lotes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IDS_.Text = "";
            LOTE_.Text = "";

            int i = 0;
            string consulta = "select clt.lote, COUNT(*) ids_usados from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo where lid.id = '" + txt_listlote.Text + "' group by clt.lote";
            SqlCommand cmd_list = new SqlCommand(consulta, session.miConexion);
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_list);
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(tabla);
            dgv_listlote.DataSource = tabla;


        }

        private void dgv_listlote_CellContentClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            LOTE_.Text = dgv_listlote.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void btn_imp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //IDS_.Text = "";
            //LOTE_.Text = "";


            int i = 0;
            string consulta = @"select lid.id
                                from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid
                                join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion
                                join concentrado_liquidacion cl on cl.cod_liquidacion = l.cod_liquidacion
                                join concentrado_liquidacion_titulo clt on clt.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo = cl.cod_concentrado_liquidacion_titulo

                                where clt.lote = '" + LOTE_.Text + "' group by lid.id";

            SqlCommand cmd_list = new SqlCommand(consulta, session.miConexion);
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_list);
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(tabla);
            dgv_ids.DataSource = tabla;

            ///////////////////////////LLENADO DATAGRIEDVIEW CENARECOM LUEGO DE IDS

            string c;
            string _lote = Convert.ToString(LOTE_.Text);
            //string query;
            float zn;
            float ag;
            string peso;
            string peso_lot;
            string peso_ant;
            string peso_next;
            //string lot;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ids.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
                {
                    c = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    zn = finos_zn(c, _lote);
                    ag = finos_ag(c, _lote);
                    peso = totaltms(c);
                    peso_lot = tmslote(c, _lote);
                    peso_ant = tms_used_ant(c);
                    peso_next = tms_sig_lote(Convert.ToSingle( peso),Convert.ToSingle( peso_ant));

                    DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
                    //  fila["id"] = Convert.ToString(id);
                    //  fila["municipio"] = Convert.ToString(muni);
                    fila["id"] = c;
                    fila["muni"] = "POTOSI";
                    fila["f_zn"] = Convert.ToString(zn);
                    fila["f_ag"] = Convert.ToString(ag);
                    fila["total_tms"] = Convert.ToSingle(peso);
                    fila["tms_lote"] = Convert.ToSingle(peso_lot);
                    fila["tms_lot_ant"] = Convert.ToString(peso_ant);
                    fila["tms_sig_lote"] = Convert.ToString(peso_next);
                    fila["lote"] = Convert.ToString(_lote);

                    dt.Rows.Add(fila);


                    /*query = "select sum(TMS) as tms_li from liquidacion_id_senarecom lid join liquidaciones l on l.cod_liquidacion = lid.cod_liquidacion where lid.id = '" + c + "' ";
                    SqlCommand t_tms = new SqlCommand(query, session.miConexion);
                    session.miConexion.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sum_total = t_tms.ExecuteReader();
                    if (sum_total.Read())
                    {
                        
                        peso = sum_total["tms_li"].ToString();
                        DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
                        fila["total_tms"] = Convert.ToSingle(peso = sum_total["tms_li"].ToString());
                        dt.Rows.Add(fila);

                    }*/


                    //session.miConexion.Close();

                    //TMS_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(tms - sum);

                }
            }
            ////////////////////IMPRIMIENDO REPORTE

            senarecom_DataSet1 ds = new senarecom_DataSet1();

            int filas = dgv_senarecom.Rows.Count;
            for(int j = 0; j <= filas -2; j++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[]
                {
                    dgv_senarecom[0, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[1, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[2, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[3, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[4, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[5, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[7, j].Value.ToString(),
                    dgv_senarecom[8, j].Value.ToString(),

                });
            }
            sena_repo sr = new sena_repo();
            
            sr.SetDataSource(ds);

            imp_sena.getimp_sena.Show();

            imp_sena.getimp_sena.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = sr;

        }
```

este es el form imp_sena donde contiene el reporte sena_repo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace liquidaciones
{
    public partial class imp_sena : Form
    {

        public static imp_sena frm;
        public static imp_sena getimp_sena
        {
            get
            {
                if(frm == null)
                {
                    frm = new imp_sena();
                }
                return frm;
            
            }
        }
        public imp_sena()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bien reivin, intentaré ayudarte, pero primero necesito entender bien tu pregunta. Primero, tienes una clase llamada `imp_sena`, en la cual, declaras una variable pública estática llamada `getimp_sena` que te devuelve la instancia de la misma clase `imp_sena`. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: añadi unas imagenes mas para verlo mejor

Comment: Amigo, acá es mejor que coloques tu código como texto, no como imágenes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con el diseño de tu clase `imp_sena` que extiende de `System.Windows.Forms` veo que intentas obtener una instancia estática de la misma en la variable pública estática `getimp_sena` para lo cual, recreas la instancia si esta es `null`, para su posterior uso.

La cuestión acá es que como está diseñada tu implementación, lo más probable es que en algún punto, el programa llame a `imp_sema.Dispose()` porque entiende que es un objeto que ya no se necesita y pretende liberar los recursos que este consume.

Apoyándome en lo anterior, te recomendaré una validación adicional: [`Control.IsDisposed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) que te dirá si el control que intentas usar fue desechado.

Tal que:

```
public static imp_sena getimp_sena
{
    if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
    {
        frm = new imp_sena();
    }

    return frm;
}
```

Un control desechado no necesariamente es `null`, por ende, aparte de la nulidad, deberías revisar si ya fue desechado para recrearlo.

Comment: gracias la validación que me mandaste sirvió ya no sale el error pero ahora cuando cierrro la ventana de reporte coloco un nuevo codigo me genera el reporte pero mas el contenido del primer codigo que use por ej. con el primer codigo el reporte me mostaba 51 filas de informacion cierro el reporte coloco un nuevo codigo y el segundo reporte que mando me muestra 98 filas de informacion es decir me muestra las 51 filas del codigo anterior mas las 47 filas del nuevo codigo